# How do I make my regular expression less greedy?

Tags: regex

My regular expression that already captures the data in a way that's satisfactory in 90% of cases, except when it gets overeager and instead of matching twice it matches both occurrences of a match

In a pseudo pattern I'm trying to capture  `#{rank} in {category}`

My existing patern

```regex
#([0-9,]+)\s*in\s*([a-z0-9&\’',+!\-\/\\(\)\:#> ]+)
```

And the what I'm trying to match against.

`Rakings: #2 in #metoo merch #4 in t-shirts, bags, and swag`

I'm hoping to match
`#2 in #metoo merch` and `#4 in t-shirts, bags, and swag` separately instead of matching the entire `#2 in #metoo merch #4 in t-shirts, bags, and swag` as one match.

I've tried lookaheads both positive and negative but I'm not quite able to crack this.

Comment: Do you absolutely want a "one-shot" regex? If not, which language are you using around that?

Comment: Yea that was the idea. If not my workaround is to split the text  with this pattern `(?=#([0-9,]+)\s*in)`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a new line at the end of the line, following regex should do the job. It matches ratings either before the next rating that starts with `#\d` OR new line which means it captures the last rating.

`(?:(#\d\sin\s.+?(?<=\s).+?)(?:(?=\s\#\d)|(?=\n))){1,}`

**Result:**
[image: Regex101.com]